# How do I reorder decimal characters to little endian?

Tags: c#, endianness

If I read a value like 12345678901234 from a textBox in C#, how can I reorder it to 34129078563412?

There aren't any spaces and the text box will always only have 14 characters.

Comment: [Have you attempted solving the problem yourself? Do you have some code we can look at?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Yes, I have tried. But i need a fresh perspective. if i post code it will be very non working

Comment: You sure your example result is correct? Shouldn't it be `34127856129034`?

Comment: It shouldn't matter that it's not perfect (just remember to say what the output of the code is). Some answers will point out mistakes in your code, which is good for improving your overall programming ability, others will give you a different approach, which gives you new knowledge, and some will do both.

Comment: My example is correct. If it was spaced out it would look like this.12 34 56 78 90 12 34. Then reordered like this 34 12 90 78 56 34 12. But being i only see example with spaces Im having a hard time building it with out them.Thanks

Comment: @MatthewWatson This example may explain it better - `1234567890` -> `9078563412`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your example, that isn't how [endian works](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). Endian relates to the byte order of numbers in binary and has nothing to do with strings of numbers.

If you're talking about integers then you need to first convert the string to a number and then to a byte array.

So:

```
string text = "12345678901234";
long number = long.Parse(text);
byte[] numberBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(number);
if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian) Array.Reverse(numberBytes);
```

If you literally want to chop and change the numbers around then thats just basic string manipulation and nothing to do with endianness.

However you can do it like this:

```
string oldString = "12345678901234";
string newString = string.Empty;
for (int i = oldString.Length - 2; i >= 0; i -= 2)
{
    newString += oldString.Substring(i, 2);
}
```

Comment: This code works great for what Im doing. small and simple. Thanks:            string oldString = textBox12.Text;
                string newString = string.Empty;
                for (int i = oldString.Length - 2; i >= 0; i -= 2)
                {
                    newString += oldString.Substring(i, 2);
                }

                textBox13.Text = newString;

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
string s = Reorder("12345678901234");//34129078563412
//...
static string Reorder(string s) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);
    for(int i = 0; i < sb.Length / 2; i += 2) {
        Reorder(sb, i, (sb.Length - 1) - i - 1);
        Reorder(sb, i + 1, (sb.Length - 1) - i);
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
static void Reorder(StringBuilder sb, int pos1, int pos2) {
    char tmp = sb[pos1];
    sb[pos1] = sb[pos2];
    sb[pos2] = tmp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok this will produce your desired result:

```
using System;

namespace Demo
{
    class Program
    {
        void Run()
        {
            string input = "12345678901234";
            string output = reorder(input);
            Console.WriteLine(output);
        }

        string reorder(string input)
        {
            var a = input.ToCharArray();

            for (int i = 0; i < a.Length/2; i += 2)
            {
                swap(ref a[i], ref a[a.Length-2-i]);
                swap(ref a[i+1], ref a[a.Length-1-i]);
            }

            return new string(a);
        }

        void swap(ref char a, ref char b)
        {
            char t = a;
            a = b;
            b = t;
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            new Program().Run();
        }
    }
}
```